# Create a sticky header and sticky sidebar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I would like to have a sticky header and menu `#fixedheader` and a sticky sidebar `#stickySocialIcons`. I already tried `position:fixed` but the problem is that the whole website gets effected...

And regarding the sticky sidebar my problem is that if I use `position:fixed` the sidebar doesn't stop at the footer with the background and that it doesn't starts to stick to the screen when the screen touches the sidebar. It is always at the same position...

Does anybody has an idea, how I can fix that?
Here the website I am talking about: https://classymagazin.de/home/

Kind regards

Comment: @Jan check my answer

Comment: @core114 Thank you!

Comment: @Jan glad to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a some idea for you , think a minuet you can do it

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dashboard</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler d-lg-none" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Settings</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 d-none d-sm-block bg-light sidebar">
          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Overview <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Reports</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Analytics</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Export</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Nav item again</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">One more nav</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Another nav item</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        
      </div>
    </div>

    
  </body>
```

and look  flowing example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/
learn bootstrap you can make it very easy
 https://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 0):

Try this css and JQuery for sticky header

```
#fixedheader {
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background: #fff;
}
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var sticky = $('#fixedheader');
var height = sticky.height();
$(document.body).css('margin-top', height + "px");
});
```